# QuickBooks Online Api Error "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request"

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-web-api, quickbooks-online, webapi

I'm using the QBO API and am at the step where I'm trying to retrieve the access and refresh tokens. When I send my request I get an error when I try to get the response that states "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request". See the code below.

I've tried a number of variations in my header, but cannot get it to work.

Any ideas?

Code (using vb.net):

```
Sub Step2_GetTokens()
    'Delcare variables. 
    Dim vHTTPREQUEST As HttpWebRequest
    Dim vHTTPRESPONSE As HttpWebResponse
    Dim vSTREAMOBJECT As Stream
    Dim vSTREAMREADER As StreamReader
    Dim vSTREAMDATA As String

    Dim vAUTHORIZATIONCODE As String
    Dim vREDIRECTURI As String
    Dim vCLIENTID As String
    Dim vCLIENTSECRET As String
    Dim vURI As String
    Dim vTOKEN As String

    'Set variables. 
    vAUTHORIZATIONCODE = "myauthorizationcodefrompreviousstep"
    vREDIRECTURI = "http://localhost:8000/myredirectpage.aspx"
    vCLIENTID = "myclientid"
    vCLIENTSECRET = "myclientsecret"

    'Set URI and Token. 
    vURI = String.Format("https://oauth.platform.intuit.com/oauth2/v1/tokens/bearer?grant_type=authorization_code&code={0}&redirect_uri={1}", vAUTHORIZATIONCODE, vREDIRECTURI)
    vTOKEN = "Basic " + System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(vCLIENTID + ":" + vCLIENTSECRET))

    'Create and send Http request.
    vHTTPREQUEST = CType(WebRequest.Create(vURI), HttpWebRequest)
    vHTTPREQUEST.Method = "POST"
    vHTTPREQUEST.ContentLength = 0
    vHTTPREQUEST.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
    vHTTPREQUEST.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    vHTTPREQUEST.Accept = "application/json"
    vHTTPREQUEST.Headers.Add("Authorization", vTOKEN)

    'Return Http response.   THE ERROR OCCURS AT NEXT LINE
    vHTTPRESPONSE = CType(vHTTPREQUEST.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
    vSTREAMOBJECT = vHTTPRESPONSE.GetResponseStream()
    vSTREAMREADER = New StreamReader(vSTREAMOBJECT, Text.Encoding.UTF8)
    vSTREAMDATA = vSTREAMREADER.ReadToEnd()

    'Display results from respense.
    TextBox1.Text = vSTREAMDATA

    'All done. 
    vHTTPRESPONSE.Close()
    vSTREAMREADER.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Would [that](https://help.developer.intuit.com/s/question/0D50f000052ag5L/get-error-400-bad-request-when-attempting-to-get-an-access-token) be helpful ?

Comment: Thanks for the response but no. The solution to that was to OP was using the wrong paramater in the URI request (they used 'redirect_url' and should have used 'redirect_uri'). That was not my problem. I using the correct parameters as far as I can tell.

Comment: Do you need to specify both credentials and a token.  I admit, I'm pretty rusty on OAuth but are the credentials even needed?  Apart from that I would be checking the encoding on the token.  Might be better to encode the vCLIENTID and vCLIENTSECRET separately and then build your token

Comment: @ptownbro, you are so welcome. I'm curious, which part of your code starts the httpListenter ?

Comment: @Hursey If you talking about the ".credentials" line, you are likely right they are not needed. But, if I take that out I still get the error. Also I don't think the encoding suggestion is correct because it needs the ":" text to connect them. Plus, I tried useing the resulting string after the encoding and that also returned the same error.

Comment: I was meaning something more like System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(vCLIENTID) + ":" + System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(vCLIENTSECRET)

Comment: @evry1falls. To answer your question I don't know unlesss it's done indirectly by the "webrequest.create" line... but I'm unsure. However, I don't think an explicit start of the httplistner is needed. I've used this code with several other API's and never have issue. It just isn't working with QuickBook's API

Comment: @Hursey. That wouldn't work for sure. It would return a "{encodedstring}:{encodedstring}" which is incorrect. QuickBooks provides a "playground" to test this and shows the result of what the full encoded string should look like and mine matches exactly to their results. So I don't think that is the issue ... but always leave room for being wrong =D

Comment: @ptownbro, I've experienced different APIs that explicitly uses `httplistener.start`, but I haven't used QuckBooks yet (But very soon). Good Luck

Comment: Ok, so I would be testing the calls I'm making via postman to make sure I'm getting the correct responses.  I'm also wondering why you aren't using the documented SDK and tools from [here](https://developer.intuit.com/) which seem to do a fair amount of the heavy lifting for you

Comment: @hursey. Yes. I tried using postman and got same error. I even tried with a simpler get request to QB with a token already provided. And, I know of the SDK and thought of using as last resort, but I wanted to be able reuse past code so I understood/learned what was going on and to be honest I didn't like the looks of their SDK.

Comment: Some new info from the QB forum where I also asked for help. They intiuit group themselves said "the request body should contain grant_type=authorization_code, code=<<here goes the authorization code>>, redirect_uri=<<here goes the redirect uri>>". My "request URI" has that, but do you know what they mean by "request body"?

Comment: Well, my opinion is use the supplied SDK, for this very reason.  As much as you might not like it, why re-invent the wheel when all this is already handled for you out of the box

Comment: @Hursey You make a valid point. I was able to find the answer however. Thanks for your help regardless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hooray! I got the answer to my question from an Intuit Developer on their forum, but wanted to share here as well in case others are looking. The issue was I needed to place the parameters that were in my URI in the HTTP request body instead of in the URI itself.

To be more specific, the following part of my original code snippet sets the value for the URI being passed to the request. If you look closely it has the parameters "grant_type", "code", and "redirect_uri". Those need to be removed from here and added to the body of the HTTP POST request instead.

```
vURI = String.Format("https://oauth.platform.intuit.com/oauth2/v1/tokens/bearer?grant_type=authorization_code&code={0}&redirect_uri={1}", vAUTHORIZATIONCODE, vREDIRECTURI)
```

Not sure why, or why they set it up that way but it is what it is... something to look into later. For now, here is the full revised code below that works perfectly.

Before you get there, note a couple other changes made that didn't really have any impact, but you should likely be aware of.

1. I removed the line "vHTTPREQUEST.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials" because it was not necessary as pointed out by @evry1falls
2. I moved and changed the line "vHTTPREQUEST.ContentLength = 0" to be based on the byte length (see new section added). This matched the suggested change from the developer and likely better practice than what I did originally.

Here is the sample code that I based my solution on that I got from the Intuit developer. It's in "c", so I converted it to "vb".

https://github.com/IntuitDeveloper/OAuth2-Dotnet-WithoutSDK/blob/08d47724c5879d30da9cd8d6b365751514462953/OAuth2_SampleApp_Dotnet/OAuth2Manager.aspx.cs#L423

Here's the new code (using vb.net)

```
Sub step2_get_token()
    'Delcare variables. 
    Dim vHTTPREQUEST As HttpWebRequest
    Dim vHTTPRESPONSE As HttpWebResponse
    Dim vSTREAMOBJECT As Stream
    Dim vSTREAMREADER As StreamReader
    Dim vSTREAMDATA As String

    Dim vAUTHORIZATIONCODE As String
    Dim vREDIRECTURI As String
    Dim vCLIENTID As String
    Dim vCLIENTSECRET As String
    Dim vURI As String
    Dim vTOKEN As String

    'Set variables. 
    vAUTHORIZATIONCODE = "myauthorizationcodefrompreviousstep"
    vREDIRECTURI = "http://localhost:8000/myredirectpage.aspx"
    vCLIENTID = "myclientid"
    vCLIENTSECRET = "myclientsecret"

    'Set URI and Token. NOTE: I removed the parameters from the URI. 
    vURI = "https://oauth.platform.intuit.com/oauth2/v1/tokens/bearer"
    vTOKEN = "Basic " + System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(vCLIENTID + ":" + vCLIENTSECRET))

    'Create a Http request with the appropriate headers. NOTE: I removed the credentials line and moved the content length line.
    vHTTPREQUEST = CType(WebRequest.Create(vURI), HttpWebRequest)
    vHTTPREQUEST.Method = "POST"
    vHTTPREQUEST.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    vHTTPREQUEST.Accept = "application/json"
    vHTTPREQUEST.Headers.Add("Authorization", vTOKEN)

    '*** HERE IS THE SECTION I ADDED ***
    'Build request body. Not sure how this is working, but it works. (You can use UTF8 or ASCII)
    Dim vHTTPREQUESTBODY As String = String.Format("grant_type=authorization_code&code={0}&redirect_uri={1}", vAUTHORIZATIONCODE, System.Uri.EscapeDataString(vREDIRECTURI))
    Dim vBYTEVERSIONOFBODY As Byte() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(vHTTPREQUESTBODY)
    vHTTPREQUEST.ContentLength = vBYTEVERSIONOFBODY.Length
    Dim vDATASTREAM As Stream = vHTTPREQUEST.GetRequestStream()
    vDATASTREAM.Write(vBYTEVERSIONOFBODY, 0, vBYTEVERSIONOFBODY.Length)
    vDATASTREAM.Close()
    '*** END OF THE SECTION I ADDED ***

    'Send Http request and get a repsonse. The "GetResponse" method both sends a request to an Internet resource and returns a WebResponse instance.
    vHTTPRESPONSE = CType(vHTTPREQUEST.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
    vSTREAMOBJECT = vHTTPRESPONSE.GetResponseStream()
    vSTREAMREADER = New StreamReader(vSTREAMOBJECT, Text.Encoding.UTF8)
    vSTREAMDATA = vSTREAMREADER.ReadToEnd()

    'Set output parameter.
    TextBox1.Text = vSTREAMDATA

    'All done. 
    vHTTPRESPONSE.Close()
    vSTREAMREADER.Close()
End Sub
```