# How does a Body get applied to an HTTP request?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, httprequest, webapi

In a previous post (link below) I was able to figure out how to apply a body to an HTTP request using VB.NET and the HttpWebRequest class object. However, I'm trying to understand how this is working technically. In other words:

How is the body actually being added to the http request because I don't see it being assigned to a property of the request object?

Here's the code snippet.

```
Dim vHTTPREQUESTBODY As String = "the body of the request"
Dim vBYTEVERSIONOFBODY As Byte() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(vHTTPREQUESTBODY)
vHTTPREQUEST.ContentLength = vBYTEVERSIONOFBODY.Length
Dim vDATASTREAM As Stream = vHTTPREQUEST.GetRequestStream()
vDATASTREAM.Write(vBYTEVERSIONOFBODY, 0, vBYTEVERSIONOFBODY.Length)
vDATASTREAM.Close()
```

Any help appreciated and more information below for those interested.

---

More Information

Why the question:

What is confusing to me is that you cannot clearly see where/how the body is added to the request before it is sent. As in older VB objects doing the same, there would be simple “Body” property for that object to set a value to. For example, in line 3 of the above, you can see the “vHTTPREQUEST.ContentLength” property set. However, you don’t see something like that for the body as in “vHTTPREQUEST.BodyOrBlahBlahBlah”. Yet, somehow the above does add the body string you set in the “vHTTPREQUESTBODY” variable to the request.

Can anyone explain how? I've search online and nothing specifically addresses this.

This is my guess:

Take a look at line 5. If you look up the “Write” method of the “Stream” object it basically states what is happening is that you are adding the bytes you placed in the first parameter of that method to the end of the current stream. So... I’m assuming what is happening is that the stream is in the computer’s memory at that point of the code, and when you use the “Write” method you are adding your body in the form of bytes to that stream that is already in memory. Therefore, you don’t need to explicitly assign it to a request of the property. Again that is a guess. I was hoping for confirmation or the true explanation or a resource/reference where I can read about this.

Previous Post:

[Here's a link to previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62248840/quickbooks-online-api-error-the-remote-server-returned-an-error-400-bad-requ)

Comment: I would deduce the same as you as to what is happening.  The first place to look for more information would be the MSDN docs on GetRequestStream, but the MSDN docs aren't always particularly informative.

Comment: Yes. I read through those as much as I could. Also, looked at a number of other resources and none address this specifically.